# NG-Show based upon refering URL

Tags: angularjs

Can I use NG-Show to display a button based upon the internal page the user came from.

For example:
We have 3 pages: Home, About, Middle Man.

Two buttons: Back to Home, Back to About.

On the Middle Man page I want only one button to display based upon what page the user was on prior.  So

```
<button ng-show="?">Back to Home</button>
<button ng-show="?">Back to About</button>
```

Comment: Yes, u can show. If you provide some code or set one flag home - H , about- A , Middle - M. ng-show="flag=='H'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can store the last visited page using a `factory` for example and display the correct buttons based on that value. The `factory` should look like this:

```
myApp.factory('historyFactory', function() {
    var _lastVisitedPage;

    return {
        setLastVisitedPage: function(page) {
            _lastVisitedPage = page;
        },
        getLastVisitedPage: function() {
            return _lastVisitedPage;
        }
    }
});
```